# What is the difference between .. and ...?

Tags: syntax, rust, range

The title is pretty much self-explanatory: When should one use the double-dots `..` and when the triple-dots `...`? Both are used to indicate a range.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While ranges with [double dots](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) don't include the end bound, triple dots were used for inclusive ranges, i.e. `(0...2)` would contain `2` as well. This is now obsolete; use [`..=`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeInclusive.html) for this purpose instead.